# Flutter/Dart Google Maps re-render widget upon mapcontroller update

Tags: google-maps, dart, flutter

How do I make the Google Map widget to re-render upon changes by made by map controllers?

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GoogleMap(
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      options: GoogleMapOptions(
        compassEnabled: true,
        cameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(-36.8446085, 174.7547239),
          zoom: 15.0,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

The method updates by using the map controller to add a marker and animate zoom according to the user's current location. This method is run by a FAB triggering `StreamController` at the parent widget of this google map rendering widget.

```
void _populateUserLocation() {
    _getLocation().then((location) {
      setState(() {
        userLocation = LatLng(location['latitude'], location['longitude']);
      });
    });
    _mapController.addMarker(
      MarkerOptions(
        position: userLocation,
        infoWindowText: InfoWindowText("!", "Your are here"),
      )
    );
    _mapController.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(
          target: userLocation,
          tilt: 50.0,
          zoom: 20.0,
        )
      )
    );
  }
```

Currently this works as intended only on the second FAB press. Meaning that the map is not being re-rendered appropriately to the changes made by the map controller.

Comment: have you found a good solution to the map re-rendering upon new position?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this like this:

```dart
Future<void> _populateUserLocation() async {
 final location = await _getLocation(); // <-- async call waits until _getLocation completes
 userLocation = LatLng(location['latitude'], location['longitude']);
 setState(() {
   _mapController.addMarker(
      MarkerOptions(
        position: userLocation,
        infoWindowText: InfoWindowText("!", "Your are here"),
      )
    );
    _mapController.animateCamera(
      CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(
        CameraPosition(
          target: userLocation,
          tilt: 50.0,
          zoom: 20.0,
        )
      )
    );
  });
}
```